# Stretching a rod?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science, stress-strain

The stress applied on a rod is linearly proportional to its strain. But shouldn't the opposite be true? I mean if you pull particles further apart doesn't the force they apply on each other decrease because the distance between them increases? Kinda like gravity?

Comment: That is not the correct interpretation of the stress-strain curve. The $\sigma$ vs. $\varepsilon$ curve gives you the amount of stress required to create a certain strain (or elongation) in the test piece. In other words, strain is a result of the stress, not the cause of the stress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we need to understand the force between individual atoms.  At relatively large separations (e.g., a few atomic diameters) atoms attract each other with a force that does, as you suggest, get weaker with distance due to polarization and ionic effects that we needn't go into here. If that was all there was to the story, however, collections of atoms would all end up at zero separation, become arbitrarily dense, and spontaneously form black holes.  There would be no "rods" in the first place!

Fortunately, at very small separations, atoms *repel* each other due to the large positive charges on their nuclei.  That repulsive force is much stronger than the attractive force at small separations, but falls off much faster as the separation increases.

As a result there is a unique separation at which the attractive force is balanced by the repulsive force.  Moreover, this equilibrium separation is *maintained* (i.e., it is a "*stable* equilibrium") due to the facts that

1) If the atoms are actively pulled apart to a slightly larger separation distance, the now larger attractive force will try to pull the atoms back together and

2) If the atoms are actively pushed together to a slightly smaller separation distance, the now larger repulsive force will try to push the atoms back apart.

All of the above is illustrated in the graph below.  Notice that the attractive and repulsive forces balance at the equilibrium separation producing zero net force.
[image: Attractive, repulsive, and net interatomic forces as functions of interatomic separation]
Notice also that for small increases in separation the net force becomes attractive.  Notice especially, that for very, *very*, small increases in separation (the kind that you get when you try to stretch a rod) the net force, the "stress," becomes more attractive in nearly direct (i.e., linear) proportion to the *increase* in separation, the "strain."

Finally, notice that, if you increase the separation by *enough*, then the net attractive force *does* start decreasing again … as you'd expect if you rip the atoms far enough apart.

Answer (score 0):

The stress applied to a rod is proportional to strain - upto the elastic limit.
I suspect you are reading a definition of stress/strain for [Hooke's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law)